# How to create Configurable Product with radio buttons ? (product size must be listed with `radio button` in product details page)

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Now how `magento` offer in `Configurable Product`, attribute set must be `Dropdown` and attributes cope must be `Global`.

My client requirement is, product size must be listed with `radio button` in product details page. Not selection box.

Without customization any settings or Extensions available for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this article written by Mladen Lotar ( ex. Inchooer )
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/configurable-product-modification-in-magento/

I believe, that you will find the answer there also if you have any problems check the comments of the article.